# Como hago para completar la pagina con dos inline-block?

Tags: html, css

Tengo un aside con width 25vw y el section de 75vw que en teoria el largo total de ambos seria de 100vw, de manera que ocupen el largo de la pantalla, el section tiene un margin-left de -4px para quitar la separación que hay entre dos inline-block (aside y section tienen display inline-block), pero me resulta que el section al tener un tamaño de 75vw, este se posiciona automaticamente debajo del aside, y si disminuyo el tamaño del section a 74vw, entonces queda un espacio en blanco del lado derecho de la pantalla despues del section. Mi pregunta es, cómo hago para rellenar ese espacio con el section, y que este no se posicione debajo del aside? Soy nuevo en html y css.

Mi codigo html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="esp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Hola Mundo </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../CSS/AprendiendoCSS/HolaMundo.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="encabezado">
        <h1> Hola Mundo </h1>
    </header>
    <nav class="nav">
        <h1 class="nav__titulo"> Barra de navegacion </h1>
        <input class="nav__input">
        <input type="button" value="Boton" class="nav__button">
    </nav>
    <aside class="apartado">
        <h1> Apartado </h1>
    </aside>
    <section class="section">
        <h1> Principal </h1>
    </section>
    <footer class="footer">
        <h1> Pie de pagina </h1>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Mi codigo css:

```
h1 {
    border-block: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.encabezado {
    background-color: #080e20;
    border: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.nav {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #ffa200;
}

.nav__titulo {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 20vw;
    color: #080e20;
}

.nav__input {
    width: 25vw;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-color: black;
}

.nav__button {
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: #080e20;
    color: white;
}

.apartado {
    color: white;
    background-color: #a6afc8;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 25vw;
    height: 50vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.section {
    color: white;
    margin: -4px;
    background-color: #0f100f;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70vw;
    height: 50vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
    height: 38vh;
    color: white;
    background-color: #0d1634;
}
```

Comment: En este caso, dos imagenes que muestren el problema vendrian genial ;)

Answer (score 0):

porque no usas flexbox?
acá te dejo la solución que le di con flexbox y te cambie las etiquetas html `aside` y `section` por `div`

```css
  h1 {
    border-block: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.encabezado {
    background-color: #080e20;
    border: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.nav {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #ffa200;
}

.nav__titulo {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 20vw;
    color: #080e20;
}

.nav__input {
    width: 25vw;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-color: black;
}

.nav__button {
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: #080e20;
    color: white;
}
.flexbox-contenedor {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.apartado {
    color: white;
    background-color: #a6afc8;
    width: 25%;
    height: 50vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.section {
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #0f100f;
    width: 75%;
    height: 50vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
    height: 38vh;
    color: white;
    background-color: #0d1634;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="esp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Hola Mundo </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../CSS/AprendiendoCSS/HolaMundo.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="encabezado">
        <h1> Hola Mundo </h1>
    </header>
    <nav class="nav">
        <h1 class="nav__titulo"> Barra de navegacion </h1>
        <input class="nav__input">
        <input type="button" value="Boton" class="nav__button">
    </nav>
    <div class="flexbox-contenedor">
        <div class="apartado">
            <h1> Apartado </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <h1> Principal </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <footer class="footer">
        <h1> Pie de pagina </h1>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Pero por otro lado si quieres mantener las mismas etiquetas html, usa `%` como valor del ancho del contenedor, luego agrega `float: left;` a los contenedores y por ultimo agrega `clear: both;` en el `footer`

el código te quedaría así:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="esp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Hola Mundo </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../CSS/AprendiendoCSS/HolaMundo.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="encabezado">
        <h1> Hola Mundo </h1>
    </header>
    <nav class="nav">
        <h1 class="nav__titulo"> Barra de navegacion </h1>
        <input class="nav__input">
        <input type="button" value="Boton" class="nav__button">
    </nav>
    <aside class="apartado">
        <h1> Apartado </h1>
    </aside>
    <section class="section">
        <h1> Principal </h1>
    </section>
    <footer class="footer">
        <h1> Pie de pagina </h1>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
    h1 {
    border-block: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.encabezado {
    background-color: #080e20;
    border: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.nav {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #ffa200;
}

.nav__titulo {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 20vw;
    color: #080e20;
}

.nav__input {
    width: 25vw;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-color: black;
}

.nav__button {
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-color: black;
    background-color: #080e20;
    color: white;
}

.apartado {
    color: white;
    background-color: #a6afc8;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 25%;
    height: 50vh;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.section {
    color: white;
    background-color: #0f100f;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 75%;
    height: 50vh;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer {
    clear: both;
    height: 38vh;
    color: white;
    background-color: #0d1634;
}
```

cualquier cosa me comentas, suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias, me gustó mucho la idea de usar div